# How to use CredentialProvider.VSS programmatically

Tags: c#, nuget, azure-devops

I'm trying to access a Nuget repository using

```
PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(Uri)
```

To access the nuget feed I need credentials which I believe CredentialProvider.VSS can provide.

What I can't find is how to glue the two together

Comment: The CredentialProvider.VSS.exe is a tool and it will prompt a window to login if not authentication, what's your detail requirement? Can you provide the simple workflow? On the other hand, how about call Nuget sources add command with username and password?

Comment: I want to connect to a nuget feed hosted in VSTS

Answer (score 0):

You can add the feed directly by calling `CredentialProvider.VSS.exe` with the parameter `-U` .For example:

```
D:\CredentialProviderBundle>CredentialProvider.VSS.exe -U https://*.visualstudio.com/_packaging/*/nuget/v3/index.json
```

Then simply run `nuget.exe restore` in your solution folder.

Maybe you also find this helpful: [Authenticating feeds with nuget.exe credential providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/extensibility/nuget-exe-credential-providers#using-a-credential-provider-from-an-environment-variable)